# Sub-models in scenes?

Tags: modeling, linked-data, scene

I have never used Blender before. Is it possible to create a hierarchical super-model or "scene" that contains the lighting, camera and so forth, and have it reference multiple sub-models stored in separate files? What I mean is, I want to be able to edit the sub-models separately and have the changes automatically be reflected in the hierarchical super-model. How do I set this up?

Let me know if you need me to explain this more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, this is possible through *linking* objects.

In the master scene file simply go to *file* > *link* or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, choose the file you want to link an object from, go to *object* and select the object.  Then when you change the files containing the objects they will change in the master file.

Linked objects will be highlighted with light blue.
[image]

Something to keep in mind is that **you can't edit the linked objects in the master file** which makes it cumbersome to make small adjustments.

Comment: You can't nest objects in hierarchical trees it seems, which is a big drawback for me. :(

Comment: @posfan12  Do you mean across files?  Within a file you can use parenting.

Comment: I mean, nesting models within models nested in other models nested in other models, and so on.